# Breeze and Point In Time Entities

Tags: sql, entity-framework, breeze

We are creating a system that allows users to create and modify bills for their clients. The modifications need to be maintained as part of the bill for auditing purposes. It is to some extent a point in time architecture but we aren't tracking by time just by revision. This is a ASP.NET MVC 5, WebAPI2, EntityFramework 6, SQL Server app using Breeze on the client and the server.

I'm trying to figure how to get back the Breeze and our data model to work correctly. When we modify an entity we essentially keep the old row, make a copy of it with the modifications and update some entity state fields w/ date/time/revision number and so on. We can always get the most recent version of the entity based off of an entity ID and an EditState field where "1" is the most current.

I made a small sample app to work on getting Breeze working as part of the solution and to enable some nice SPA architecture and inline editing on the client and it all works... except that since our entity framework code automatically creates a new entity that contains the modifications, the SaveChanges response contains the original entity but not the new "updated" entity. Reloading the data on the client works but it would of course be dumb to do that outside of just hacking around for demo purposes.

So I made a new ContextProvider and inherited from EFContextProvider, overrode the AfterSaveEntities method and then things got a bit more complicated. Not all the entities have this "point in time" / revision functionality but most of them do. If they do I can as I said above get the latest version of that entity using its EntityId and EditState but I'm not seeing a straight forward way to get the new entity (pretty new to EF and very new to Breeze) so I'm hoping to find some pointers here.

Would this solution lie in Breeze or our DataContext? I could just do some reflection, get the type, query the updated entity and shove that into the saveMap. It seems like that might break down at some point (not sure how or when but seems sketchy). Is our architecture bad? Should we have gone the route of creating audit/log tables to store the modified values instead of keeping the datamodel somewhat smaller by keeping all of the revisions of the entities in their original tables but with the revision information and making the queries slightly more complicated? Am I just missing something in EF?

... and to head of the obvious response, I know we should have used a document database but that wasn't an option on this project. We are stuck in relational land.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this but another approach would be to simply change the EntityState of the incoming entity in the BeforeSaveEntities method from Modified to Added.  You will probably need to also update some version field in this 'new' entity so that it doesn't have a primary key conflict with the original.

But... having built apps like this in the past, I really recommend another approach.  Store your 'historical' entities of each type in a separate table. It can be exactly the same shape as the 'current' table.  When you save you first copy the 'current' entity into the 'historical' table ( again with some version numbering or date schema for the primary key) and then just update your 'current' entity normally.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll be working this today. We shied away from the history tables since the history is an important aspect of this billing document and not strictly for traditional auditing or change tracking. Those modifications are part of documents lifecycle until it gets billed and we didn't want to make the querying overly complicated... simple in one place -> more complex somewhere else. btw. BREEZE IS AMAZING. I've been ripping through Noye's Pluralsight series and am amazed by how much time we've spent dealing with the results of architectures pre-Breeze/MV*M/ORM

Answer (score 0):

This might not give you the answer you expected, but here is an idea:

When saving an object, intercept save on server, you get an instance of object you need to modify, read object from database that has the same ID, put copy of that old object to legacy table in your database and continue with saving into main table. That way only latest revision stays in main table while legacy table would contain all previous versions.

So, all you would need to do is have two tables containing same objects:

```
public DbSet<MyClass> OriginalMyClasses{get;set;}
public DbSet<MyClass> LegacyMyClasses{get;set;}
```

override SaveChanges function and intercept when entry E state is Modified, read E type, get the original and legacy tables, read object O from Original with same ID as E, save O to Legacy table, and finally return base.SaveChanges(); (let it save as it is supposed to by default).